# PHP - Problems with function return and multidimensional array

Tags: php, function, multidimensional-array

I have the next issue, I have this multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-14 07:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-14 07:20
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-14 07:20
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-14 07:40
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-14 07:40
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-14 08:00
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-14 08:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-14 08:15
                    [type] => 3
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-14 08:15
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-14 08:30
                    [type] => 3
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-15 07:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-15 07:20
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-15 07:20
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-15 07:40
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-15 07:40
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-15 08:00
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-15 08:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-15 08:15
                    [type] => 3
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-15 08:15
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-15 08:30
                    [type] => 3
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-18 07:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-18 07:20
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-18 07:20
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-18 07:40
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-18 07:40
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-18 08:00
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-18 08:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-18 08:15
                    [type] => 3
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-18 08:15
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-18 08:30
                    [type] => 3
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-19 07:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-19 07:20
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-19 07:20
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-19 07:40
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-19 07:40
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-19 08:00
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-19 08:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-19 08:15
                    [type] => 3
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-19 08:15
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-19 08:30
                    [type] => 3
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-20 07:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-20 07:20
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-20 07:20
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-20 07:40
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-20 07:40
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-20 08:00
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-20 08:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-20 08:15
                    [type] => 3
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-20 08:15
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-20 08:30
                    [type] => 3
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-21 07:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-21 07:20
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-21 07:20
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-21 07:40
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-21 07:40
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-21 08:00
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-21 08:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-21 08:15
                    [type] => 3
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-21 08:15
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-21 08:30
                    [type] => 3
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-22 07:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-22 07:20
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-22 07:20
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-22 07:40
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-22 07:40
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-22 08:00
                    [type] => 2
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-22 08:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-22 08:15
                    [type] => 3
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [start_date] => 2016-07-22 08:15
                    [end_date] => 2016-07-22 08:30
                    [type] => 3
                )

        )

)
```

In addition, I have the following function:

```
public function transformValue($array = [], $level = 1) {
    $return = [];
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            $this->transformValue($value, $level + 1);
        } else{
            $return[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $return;

}
```

This function receives this multi-array as a parameter, as I need to normalize it as follows:

```
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-14 07:00
    [end_date] => 2016-07-14 07:20
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-14 07:20
    [end_date] => 2016-07-14 07:40
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-14 07:40
    [end_date] => 2016-07-14 08:00
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-14 08:00
    [end_date] => 2016-07-14 08:15
    [type] => 3
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-14 08:15
    [end_date] => 2016-07-14 08:30
    [type] => 3
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-15 07:00
    [end_date] => 2016-07-15 07:20
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-15 07:20
    [end_date] => 2016-07-15 07:40
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-15 07:40
    [end_date] => 2016-07-15 08:00
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-15 08:00
    [end_date] => 2016-07-15 08:15
    [type] => 3
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-15 08:15
    [end_date] => 2016-07-15 08:30
    [type] => 3
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-18 07:00
    [end_date] => 2016-07-18 07:20
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-18 07:20
    [end_date] => 2016-07-18 07:40
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-18 07:40
    [end_date] => 2016-07-18 08:00
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-18 08:00
    [end_date] => 2016-07-18 08:15
    [type] => 3
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-18 08:15
    [end_date] => 2016-07-18 08:30
    [type] => 3
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-19 07:00
    [end_date] => 2016-07-19 07:20
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-19 07:20
    [end_date] => 2016-07-19 07:40
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-19 07:40
    [end_date] => 2016-07-19 08:00
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-19 08:00
    [end_date] => 2016-07-19 08:15
    [type] => 3
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-19 08:15
    [end_date] => 2016-07-19 08:30
    [type] => 3
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-20 07:00
    [end_date] => 2016-07-20 07:20
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-20 07:20
    [end_date] => 2016-07-20 07:40
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-20 07:40
    [end_date] => 2016-07-20 08:00
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-20 08:00
    [end_date] => 2016-07-20 08:15
    [type] => 3
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-20 08:15
    [end_date] => 2016-07-20 08:30
    [type] => 3
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-21 07:00
    [end_date] => 2016-07-21 07:20
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-21 07:20
    [end_date] => 2016-07-21 07:40
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-21 07:40
    [end_date] => 2016-07-21 08:00
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-21 08:00
    [end_date] => 2016-07-21 08:15
    [type] => 3
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-21 08:15
    [end_date] => 2016-07-21 08:30
    [type] => 3
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-22 07:00
    [end_date] => 2016-07-22 07:20
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-22 07:20
    [end_date] => 2016-07-22 07:40
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-22 07:40
    [end_date] => 2016-07-22 08:00
    [type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-22 08:00
    [end_date] => 2016-07-22 08:15
    [type] => 3
)
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2016-07-22 08:15
    [end_date] => 2016-07-22 08:30
    [type] => 3
)
```

**MY PROBLEM**: When I call my function and assigned to a variable, it appears that the function does not assign any value to the variable, but if I check the return of the function with a print_r() shows the values as we need. I should be skipping is things and I need a "push" to continue. It is in this way that declare the variable with the return of function:

```
$return_value_function = [];
$return_value_function = $this->transformValue($array_values);
```

The variable $return_value_function does not save the function return. Where is my mistake?

Comment: `$this->transformValue($value, $level + 1);` returns what and to what variable?

Comment: I don't get what does `$level` used for.

Comment: @Chay22 $level is used to determine the depth of the array, the function is recursive.

Comment: @u_mulder $level It is initialized to 1 in the function and increases its value until find the values in the multi-array

Comment: Do you understand that call `$this->transformValue($value, $level + 1)` returns some data into a void?

Comment: @u_mulder if I call print_r ($return) before the return of function, shows me the values correctly, but the variable $return_value_function does not take the value returned by the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the value from this call:

`$this->transformValue($value, $level + 1);`

to a variable. Like:

`$return[$key] = $this->transformValue($value, $level + 1);`

Everytime this function is called recursively, the `return` statement sends the data back & there is nothing to hold that returned data.

**SOLUTION**

You can change your function as below & achieve the same output without recursion:

```
function transformValue($array = []) {
$return = [];
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        $return = array_merge( $return, $value );
    }
}
return $return;
}
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 01 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 02 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 03 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 04 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 05 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 1
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 06 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 2
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 07 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 2
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 08 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 2
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 09 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 2
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 10 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 2
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 11 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 3
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 12 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 3
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 13 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 3
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 14 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 3
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 15 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 3
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 16 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 4
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 17 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 4
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 18 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 4
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 19 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 4
    )

[19] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 20 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 4
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 21 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 5
    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 22 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 5
    )

[22] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 23 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 5
    )

[23] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 24 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 5
    )

[24] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 25 Jul, 2016
        [type] => 5
    )
)
```

Please note my sample array only contains those 2 keys.

And this output is returned through the following code:

```
$return_value_function = [];
$return_value_function = transformValue($arr);
echo '<pre>';print_r($return_value_function);echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not with the function. If I call print_r($return) before the return of function, shows me the values correctly, but the variable $return_value_function does not take the value returned by the function

Comment: Great. Can you please mark this as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code. It will return array as you wish.

```
public function transformValue($array) {        
    foreach($array as $subarray){
        foreach($subarray as $value){
            $finalArray[] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $finalArray;

}

$finalArray= $this->transformValue($array_values);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($finalArray);
```